# References not added to TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I am hoping for a little advice.

I am checking in my project (asp.net mvc 5) to source control (TFS) and when a fellow colleague tries to pull it down, most of the references are not being added to his project.

How can I insure that all the references to get added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, best practice is to use NuGet.

At least for packages that are not internal you must use NuGet. Let's say for EF, BundleTransformer & so on.

For that you must enable NuGet package restore and fetch all you need from NuGet Feed. More here: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated

For internal dll's you can create an internal NuGet feed: https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds and get packages from there or copy them in your project.

Don't forget to include the files into project if you copy them "by hand" and i think this is a good start.

There are other best practices like not referencing anything from GAC anymore and move all the dll's/dependencies/referencing to NuGet or to create a raw "Library/Vendor" folder in your project and copy all the necessary DLLs there (problem here is that you check in all the dll's to source control), but you will be sure that everyone will get exact the same version/reference & so on because the files are stored there (physically).

Comment: upvoted for the discussion of not referencing things in GAC, nicely put!

Answer (score 1):

What are the references to?

There are a few different things to bear in mind:

1. References to other projects within the solution should just work, if they don't make sure that the referred to projects are building
2. References to things like nunit are best managed through nuget so you add them using it and then when your colleague checks out he only has to restore the nuget packages and it all works
3. References to things that aren't in nuget, you can either put them into nuget or I prefer to create a lib folder and put them into there. To get them actually checked in as dll's are normally excluded, add the folder and dll's and then use the source control explorer to find the folder, right click and choose "Add items to folder" and use that to add the dll's and files that you need. If you then reference the dll's in the lib folder they will be checked out and should resolve correctly for the other user.